# WordPress REST API Endpoints - how can I allow multiple and optional IDs on the same endpoint?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am building a REST API custom endpoint and would like to be able to render a view for multiple posts or a singular view of a post if an ID is specified. I would also like to allow for further `?` query parameters to be allowed in both cases.

Example requests:

1. `/posts // no query parameters, use defaults`
2. `/posts?fields=id,title,thumbnail&thumbnail_size=medium`
3. `/posts/123/?fields=id,title,thumbnail&thumbnail_size=large`
4. `/posts/123 // nothing specified again!`

Here is the code I currently have:

```
register_rest_route('wp-api', '/posts/(?P<id>[^/]+)?', [
    'methods' => [WP_REST_Server::READABLE, WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE],
    'callback' => function ($request) {
        return MyClass::wp_api_get_posts($request);
    },
]);
```

This code is working for use-cases 3 and 4 but because of the `/` in the rest route, use cases 1 and 2 do not work and I simply receive the `rest_no_route` error (`No route was found matching the URL and request method`).

I believe the problem to be my regex, but I can't figure out how to fix it.